# How to know if my Magento 2 is in developer mode via PHP?

Tags: magento2, php, module

I'm using Magento 2.4 to develop a new module and I need to check if the store is running in **developer mode** or **production mode**.

How could I get the **Magento Mode** via PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your class

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
 */
private $state;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->state = $state;
    ....
}
```

Then you can use inside the class `$this->state->getMode()`;